# date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, centos, time, date

I have received an interesting problem during I tried to set my Server time either with NTD or manually using `date` command.

First of all I have tried to use NTD. I have succesfully installed the latest version of NTD, started it. After that I have wanted the synchronization to start. This is why I have run the following command: `ntpdate pool.ntp.org`

And I have received the following error:

> 18 May 15:29:21 ntpdate[15477]: step-systime: Operation not permitted

Than I did not know what to do, so I have tried to set the time manually using the `date` command:

```
rm /etc/localtime
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/GMT /etc/localtime
date 051822172013
```

However I got this error:

> date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted

Can anyone guess what could be the possible problem on my server? I'm logged in as root and I'm using CentOS 5.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

You can't set the time yourself in a shared-kernel, container-based VPS such as OpenVZ or Virtuozzo.

If the system time is wrong, contact the hosting provider. If the system time *remains* wrong, switch to another provider and consider using something other than OpenVZ.

[Problems with the system time](https://serverfault.com/a/488528/126632) is, in fact, one of the many reasons I don't use OpenVZ based VPSes for anything anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. My main problem is that I'm trying to use Amazon services and they require exact time.

Answer (score 4):

Is this a dedicated physical server or a **[VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server)**?

If it's a VPS, you may not have permissions to do this. Otherwise, running the date/ntpdate/hwclock commands should work as a root user.

If you *are* using a VPS, contact your provider to handle this for you.

Comment: It is a VPS actually. Thank you for the answer. I'll contact the provider.