# Virtual guest: NTP sync with host

Tags: virtualization, virtualhost, virtual-machines, ntp

Is there any way to get a virtual guest to only query it's current host for NTP?

I'm not talking about configuring ntp.conf with the host's IP here either as VLAN's & firewalls may block that traffic.  Also migration to a different host would require ntp reconfig & restart.  A direct (intercepted?) query from the guest to the host.

I've tried various NTP solutions and it seems to me (theoretically) that it might be best for a guest to query only it's current host for an NTP sync (notwithstanding the VMware advice not to use their sync-with-host option).

It might/would require a version of NTP that is virt-aware.

Only one NTP source would be required as the guest wouldn't be running if the host wasn't available.

Comment: Install the VMware tools. They can manage time  synchronization between guest and host.

Comment: "VMware recommends using NTP instead of VMware Tools periodic time synchronization."

http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1006427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really use NTP here because you can't know where the "host" is on the network.

Some hypervisors provide a way to synchronize time with the host. For instance, VMware provides a userspace tool in VMware Tools for this purpose. KVM has a paravirtualized RTC. And so on.

Though in my experience these are all less than perfect, and trusting the host to have the correct time is a bad idea, [necessitating running NTP in every VM](https://serverfault.com/a/488528/126632) (and having it use reliable servers) anyway.

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I figured.  There's no great solution to keeping time on a virtual guest as far as I can see.

I hoped there might be something that would allow me to remove the extra physical clocks somehow (i.e. my physical NTP servers).  I have to ensure these keep the right time, so getting the virtual hosts to do the same thing isn't a great leap I don't think.  Properly configured NTP client on the host allows me to trust it's time as much as I trust my physical NTP servers.